# CIFS Mount Error 12.04

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mount, cifs

I'm trying to CIFS mount a directory on a Windows server to a Ubuntu Apache server to act as a graphics server for a development test server for images. Im running into two separate errors, while using the same argument, but different usernames. I thought maybe my account was preventing me from mounting it but our Admin account is running into the same issue. What is the error with our argument causing this issue? Thanks a bunch...

```
root@cakestripper:~# mount -t cifs //10.16.16.253/files/public/graphics /home/www/gfx/ -o username=******,pass=******,dom=*****
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
root@cakestripper:~# mount -t cifs //10.16.16.253/files/public/graphics /home/www/gfx/ -o username=******,pass=******,dom=*****
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Comment: I strongly suggest that you put user username/domain/password into a credentials file.  You generally shouldn't pass those on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Try `user` rather than `username`, `password` rather than `pass` and `domain` rather than `dom`. Otherwise use the option `credentials=filename` and in `filename` put:

```
username=value
password=value
domain=value
```

Comment: Turns out it is a 12.04 LTS error - It worked perfectly on our 10.04.2 LTS box without any error. Weird.